# My vuejs animation/transition is lagging on path change.

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-router

[image]

I am using vue and vue-router for my portfolio. I added simple "fade" animation. And my animation is lagging.

**My App.vue component:**

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <Square/>
        <Navbar/>
    </div>
</template>
```

**My Square.vue component:**

```
<template>
    <div id="square">
        <transition name="fade">
            <router-view></router-view>
        </transition>
    </div>
</template>
<style>
    .fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
      transition: opacity 0.5s;
    }
    .fade-enter, .fade-leave-to{
      opacity: 0;
    }
 </style>
```

**My routes file:**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import Hello from './views/Hello.vue';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'hello',
      component: Hello,
    },
    {
      path: '/i-am',
      name: 'I am',
      component: () => import( 
'./views/About.vue'),
    },
    {
      path: '/i-use',
      name: 'I use',
      component: () => import( 
'./views/Using.vue'),
    },
   ],
});
```

[image: This is project structure]

And I think it is not because of the style of animation. New content renders faster than old component destroys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VueJS Transition Component has this cool props called mode.
This will add a smooth effect upon destroying the previous component.

```
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
  <!-- ... the buttons ... -->
</transition>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Modes